# upgrade inherit maven dependencies from parent pom

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies, pom.xml

in spring boot project tomcat-embed-core: 9.0.12 is getting resolved by parent dependency spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.0.

but due to some reasons we have to upgrade the tomcat-embed-core version from 9.0.12 to 9.0.20.

I have added the below dependency separately in POM,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.20</version>
</dependency>
```

now I can see V9.0.20 in dependency hierarchy, but also omitted for conflict with 9.0.20.

is this a correct way, if no then suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: So you added the updated dependency and excluded that from the spring boot parent explicitly. Are you asking if that's the expected way to handle it --- yes, it is

Comment: Yes, actually..

Comment: I believe that's all you have to do then. Do you have a follow up question?

Comment: So now message appears as "omitted for conflict" in dependency hierarchy..

Generally, if we want to remove dependencies from embedded maven dependency then we use exclusion and add upgraded one separately. But as it is resolving from parent one so can it possible to exclude inherited dependencies.